# Moving tables from one database to another with phpMyadmin no command line

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Similar questions have been asked, but I have some extra restrictions. I **do not** have access to command line because I **do not** have ssh access. I want want to get all of the table except for one moved to a different database.

One table is over 2.5gb so phpMyadmin craps out when it tries to do this. This makes it so trying to copy the database stops when it tries to copy that table.

I need to copy all of the tables except that to a different database so I can eventually export the database (which is ultimately my end goal). Or is there a way to export all of the tables expect for the big one? Like I said, I would do this with command line but I don't have access to it.

Comment: 2.5gb table and no commandline access...really? You'll probably have to contact your hosting and have them export the db for you since they'll have commandline access.

Comment: You can export via phpMyAdmin. You can also Import from there too. However you will likely run into issues about max file upload size. At which point you are screwed.

Comment: phpMyAdmin has an option on export to skip tables larger the X MB.

Comment: @cmorrissey I am not seeing this option, can you elaborate, maybe put it as an answer?

Comment: How exactly are you trying to move the tables within phpMyAdmin now?

Comment: Are you trying to copy to another database on the same server, or a completely different MySQL server?